# cucumber is failing to launch my @rerun.txt failed tests

Tags: cucumber

I was trying to execute:

```
cucumber @rerun.txt
```

and I had to add the following to my gemfile as it was failing with different errors:

```
gem "ramaze"
gem "webrat"
gem "rubypython"
```

Now, when I execute the cucumber command 'cucumber @rerun.txt', I get the following error message, any idea what could be causing this problem and how to overcome it?

```
"Don't know how to reveal method 'respond_to?' (RuntimeError)"
```